# Karma unit test Angular JS directives with externalUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to test an Angular directive that has an external template, but cannot get this to work.  This is my first attempt at using Karma.  I have Googled for a solution, and tried various changes to the karma.conf.js file, but still keep getting this:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app/inventory/itemDetails.html due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app/inventory/itemDetails.html' is not available! You     either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Folder structure:

```
app
  inventory
    itemDetails.html
    itemDetailsDirective.js  (templateUrl: "app/inventory/itemDetails.html")


UnitTest
  karma.conf.js
    specs
      inventorySpec.js
```

karma.conf.js

```
  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '../scripts/jquery.min.js',
  'scripts/angular.js',
  'scripts/angular-mocks.js',
  '../app/*.js',
  '../app/**/*.js',
  '../app/inventory/itemDetails.html',
  'specs/*.js'
  ],


preprocessors: {
    '../app/inventory/itemDetails.html':['ng-html2js'] // Is this supposed to be the path relative to the karma.conf.js file?
  },

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix: '../',
  },
```

itemDetailsDirective.js

```
templateUrl: "app/inventory/itemDetails.html",
```

inventorySpec.js (most stuff commented out for debug purposes)

```
describe("itemDetailsDirective", function () {
    var element, $scope;

    beforeEach(module("app/inventory/itemDetails.html"));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        console.log("itemDetailsDirective");
        //element = angular.element('<item-details></item-details>');
        //$scope = $rootScope.$new();
        //$compile(element)($scope);
        //$scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should display', function () {
    //    var isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();
    //    //expect(isolatedScope.condition).toEqual("Fair");
    });

});
```

So I have a UnitTest folder (VS 2013 project) parallel to the app folder.   The paths under "files" in karma.conf.js are correct - all "non-templateUrl" tests work fine.

Help would be great, while I still have some hair left!

Comment: I think you can use inject service to inject the directive inside your test and then get the templateUrl from there. I will try to write an example.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working, thanks to this article that I just came across: http://willemmulder.net/post/63827986070/unit-testing-angular-modules-and-directives-with

The key is that the paths are relative to the DISK root!

To illustrate, I changed the karma.conf.js file to use cahceIdFromPath:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    cacheIdFromPath : function(filepath) {
        console.log("karma, cacheIdFromPath " + filepath);
        var templateFile = filepath.substr(filepath.indexOf("/app/") + 1 );
        console.log("karma, templateFile: " + templateFile);
    return templateFile;
  },
},
```

Output:

```
karma, cacheIdFromPath C:/Dev/BcCom/app/inventory/itemDetails.html
karma, templateFile: app/inventory/itemDetails.html
```

With the above, it now works as it should!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want to test but you are trying to use an html as module which I think is not correct and probably you have to use `$httpbackend`to mock the GET request. I made a dummy example:

```
'use strict';
describe('TestMyDirective', function() {
  var $compile, $http, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $scope, template;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    // Inject $httpBackend service
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    // Mock request to your html
    $httpBackend.whenGET('my.html').respond("GotIT");
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    template = $compile("<my-directive> </my-directive>")($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  /*
   *
   * Tests
   *
   */
  describe('Test something', function() {
    it('should test something', function() {
       // You can test that your directive add something on the $scope
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: please check out this article about testing directives with external HTML templates: http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/unit-testing-angularjs-directives  (just one of many articles / posts I have been over, trying to get this working).